# query to select users who has answered all questions from set of answers of each question

Tags: mysql

This is mysql table.

```
            User    Question    Answer
            20      1           answer1_2
            20      2           answer2_5
            20      3           answer3_1
            726     1           answer1_2
            726     2           answer2_5
            726     3           answer3_1
```

I want the users who has given answer of all questions and 
we have predefined set of answers for each question.

like Question 1 can have answers from answer1_1, answer1_2, answer1_3
     Question 2 can have answers from answer2_1, answer2_2, answer2_3

Initially, I tried query like this:

```
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( User AS CHAR ) ) allUsers, COUNT( DISTINCT User ) totalUsers
            FROM survey
            WHERE
            (
                (
                Question =1
                AND Answer =  'answer1_2'
                )
                OR (
                Question =1
                AND Answer =  'answer1_2'
                )
                OR (
                Question =1
                AND Answer =  'answer1_3'
                )
            )
            AND (
                (
                Question =2
                AND Answer =  'answer2_1'
                )
                OR (
                Question =2
                AND Answer =  'answer2_2'
                )
                OR (
                Question =2
                AND Answer =  'answer2_3'
                )
            )
```

but then I see the result and realize that 'AND' among all questions won't work for my requirement
but I need the result with that logic.

Table structure cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
Select user, count(answer) from survey group by user having count(answer)=3
```

Comment: we have to specify possible answers per question, also.
your solution will ensure only all answers are given.

Comment: You can then link that and select all users matching the one in the query above - you didnt mention you needed the answers, you said you needed the users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique key on fields `User` and `Question`, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT count(Question) answers_no, .... FROM survey GROUP BY User HAVING answers_no = num_total_questions
```

You could pass num_total_questions as a variable from application